# How to open a file from a specific folder -- based on user selections in a dropdown menu?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, dropdown

starting a project from square 1 and I'm just trying to get an idea of how to get it started...

I want the user to be able to open an excel report based on their choices from multiple dropdown menus. The excel file names are structured as x_y_z.xls.  There are three variables: x, y, and z, that will all be categories for dropdown menus (created using html/css). When the user selects their pick from all three categories, they will click the "enter" button, which will open the corresponding excel sheet.

I was thinking of using PHP to set conditional statements to open up the files...  I just don't know how to execute it. Any pointers would be helpful since I am a beginner at this.

Thanks

Comment: You should start by doing some research and try something. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back, show us what you've tried and we'll gladly help. In it's current state, this question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fopen` in PHP. It seems you said they choose the title from a form? If so you could run a script that checks for a submission, and when it's true you setup the file name based on the form inputs:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];
    $z = $_POST['z'];

    $file = $x . '_' . $y . '_' . $z . '.csv';

    $handle = fopen($file, "r");

    // let's create an extra layer of protection
    if (file_exists($file_path))
    {
        // gets data from csv file
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            // code goes here...
            // this will return an array
        }
    }
}
```

That scripts waits for a submission, and then setup `$x`, `$y`, `$z`. Then put them together in whatever format you want. From your description I used: `$file = $x . '_' . $y . '_' . $z . '.csv';`.

That can be altered to suit your needs a bit better.